# How to use map within a map in javascript to access particular element

Tags: javascript, arrays, jsx, array-map

I have two array one is a simple array and the another is the array of objects.

Here is the arrays:-

```
arr1=["aadhar", "address", "email", "mobile", "name", "pancard", "voterid"];
```

```
arr2=[ {
            "id": 21,
            "name": "johndoe",
            "email": "hello@gmail.com",
            "address": "test address",
            "voterid": "12131313",
            "mobile": "1211313",
            "aadhar": "213123131313",
            "pancard": "HYG579AA"
        },
        {
            "id": 24,
            "name": "johndoe3",
            "email": "hello1@gmail.com",
            "address": "test address",
            "voterid": "12111313",
            "mobile": "1211313",
            "aadhar": "112313131313",
            "pancard": "YHUIHU88"
        }];
```

I want to map arr2 within arr1 to get the value using the first arr1. This is what I tried :

```
 {arr2.map((item) => {
              return (
                <Tr key={item.id}>
                  {arr1.map((itx) => {
                    return <Td>{item.itx}</Td>;
 })}
}
```

I want the item to be mapped like this:-

```
item.aadhar
item.address
item.email
item.mobile

and so on...
```

but I am unable to use the itx or arr1 after dot
i.e item.itx (itx is not being used).

Do let me know if there is any way to do this.

Comment: `arr2.map(row => <tr key={row.id}>{arr1.map(item => <td key={row.id + '_' + item}>{row[item]}</td>)}</tr>)`

Comment: Basically you got the nested map() right but you have to use the square brackets notation (`item[itx]`) instead of the dot notation (`item.itx`) because `itx` is a variable, not the name of a property of the object.

Comment: Replace `item.itx` with `item[itx]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically access object property using variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is more readable...

```js
arr2.map(row => {
  return (
    <tr key={row.id}>
      {
        arr1.map(item => {
          return (
            <td key={`${row.id}_${item}`}>
              {row[item]}
            </td>
          )
        })
      }
    </tr>
  )
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't tangle data manipulation logic with React component layout logic. Write a separate `pick(obj, fields)` function -

```js
const pick = (obj = {}, fields = []) =>
  fields.map(f => obj[f])

const arr1 = ["aadhar", "address", "email", "mobile", "name", "pancard", "voterid"]
const arr2 = [{id: 21,name: "johndoe",email: "hello@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12131313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "213123131313",pancard: "HYG579AA"},{id: 24,name: "johndoe3",email: "hello1@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12111313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "112313131313",pancard: "YHUIHU88"}]
  
console.log(arr2.map(obj => pick(obj, arr1)))
```

```js
[
  [
    "213123131313",
    "test address",
    "hello@gmail.com",
    "1211313",
    "johndoe",
    "HYG579AA",
    "12131313"
  ],
  [
    "112313131313",
    "test address",
    "hello1@gmail.com",
    "1211313",
    "johndoe3",
    "YHUIHU88",
    "12111313"
  ]
]
```

Now you can easily write your table -

```js
const rows = arr2.map(obj => pick(obj, arr1))
return <table>
  {rows.map(row =>
    <tr>{row.map(cell => <td>...</td>)}</tr>
  )}
</table>
```

Here is a complete example you can run and verify in your own browser -

```js
const pick = (obj = {}, fields = []) =>
  fields.map(f => obj[f])

function Table ({ rows, selector }) {
  return <table>
    {rows.map((row, key) =>
      <tr key={key}>
        {selector(row).map((cell, key) =>
          <td key={key}>{cell}</td>
        )}
      </tr>
    )}
  </table>
}

const arr1 = ["aadhar", "address", "email", "mobile", "name", "pancard", "voterid"]
const arr2 = [{id: 21,name: "johndoe",email: "hello@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12131313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "213123131313",pancard: "HYG579AA"},{id: 24,name: "johndoe3",email: "hello1@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12111313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "112313131313",pancard: "YHUIHU88"}]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table rows={arr2} selector={x => pick(x, arr1)}/>,
  document.querySelector("main")
)
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
td { border: 1px solid silver; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```

Here's an alternative example which includes the column headers -

```js
const pick = (obj = {}, fields = []) =>
  fields.map(f => obj[f])

function Table ({ rows, cols }) {
  return <table>
    <tr>
      {cols.map((col, key) =>
        <th key={key}>{col}</th>
      )}
    </tr>
    {rows.map((row, key) =>
      <tr key={key}>
        {pick(row, cols).map((cell, key) =>
          <td key={key}>{cell}</td>
        )}
      </tr>
    )}
  </table>
}

const arr1 = ["aadhar", "address", "email", "mobile", "name", "pancard", "voterid"]
const arr2 = [{id: 21,name: "johndoe",email: "hello@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12131313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "213123131313",pancard: "HYG579AA"},{id: 24,name: "johndoe3",email: "hello1@gmail.com",address: "test address",voterid: "12111313",mobile: "1211313",aadhar: "112313131313",pancard: "YHUIHU88"}]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Table rows={arr2} cols={arr1} />,
  document.querySelector("main")
)
```

```css
table { border: 1px solid black; }
th,td { border: 1px solid silver; }
th { font-weight: bold; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<main></main>
```